# What is the "english translation" of "if not randint(0,5):"?

Tags: python, if-statement, random

```
import random

dirty = True
scrub_count = 0


while(dirty):
    scrub_count += 1
    print('scrub the pan {}'.format(scrub_count))

    if not random.randint(0,5):
        print('all clean')
        dirty = False
    else:
        print('NOPE STILL SOME WORK TO DO')
```

I absolutely do not get how `if not random.randinit(0,5)` translates, or how that line of code renders the `scrub_count` meet the random number.

For me the logical way to put it would be .. if `scrub_count` is equal to random number then `print('all clean')`.

Comment: anything not equal to 0, is considered True. So the `randomint` call will be true 3 out of 4 times. (honestly i don't understand your question, but this might help)

Comment: @Olian04 5 in 6...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i ment to type 4 out of 5 times. But 5 out of 6? is `randomint` upper inclusive?

Comment: @Olian04 Yes; and there is also `random.randrange`.

Answer (score 3):

`not random.randint(0, 5)` will evaluate to true (truthy) whenever the return value of `random.randint(0, 5)` is `0`.

#### truthiness for emptiness

Relying on truthiness to check for emptiness is a common idiom in Python (suggested by PEP8):

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty
>   sequences are false.
>
> Yes: if not seq:
>        if seq:
>
> No: if len(seq):
>       if not len(seq):

#### truthiness for zero

I find using truthiness to check emptiness useful while checking truthiness of a number confusing. But relying on truthiness with numbers is a different matter.

I agree that this way of writing things is a bit convoluted. Personally **I'd much prefer to see `random.randint(0, 5) == 0`** instead.

Comment: I'd prefer `if random.random() <= 1/6:` which is probably easier to understand as "with a probability of 1 out of 6"...

Comment: Actually, `not random.randint(0, 5)` with evaluate to `True` when `random.randint(0, 5)` is *equal to* zero.

Comment: Fixed. Nice catch @SiHa. Thank you! I guess that's more proof that I personally find `not` on numbers un-intuitive...