# Python If statement with only an integer?

Tags: python, if-statement

I was reading python code and I stumbled upon this little snippet of code here

```
if array[index] < 0:
   return -1
if not array[index]:
   continue
```

I mainly use java, and I struggle to understand the second statement, where I can only see an integer in the if statement. Can someone please explain to me what this means?!

Comment: As there is "continue" statement in the code, I guess the above code is inside a loop. Can you post the whole code, please?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452597/what-is-the-english-translation-of-if-not-randint0-5/40452781#40452781)

Comment: In python, any value will evaluate to 'true' or 'false' in appropriate conditional contexts.  It's pretty intuitive - none, empty, zero are all false.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second conditional statement was there to check whether the `array[index]` element is not `None` (equivalent to java's `null`) or not `0`.

In python, both `not None` and `not 0` are `True`

The equivalent Java statement for the second conditional would be:

```java
if(array[index]!=null || array[index]!=0){
   continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you are normalizing a function, well the second statement

```
if not array[index]:
    continue
```

means that if there are none items on that position of the array then continue looping over the array, same goes for this condition:

```
if array[index]:
   print("found")
```

Basically evaluates the condition there's an item = true.

I hope it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

In some languages like Python and Perl, `0` is `false` and anything else (sans `None`) is `true`. So `not 0` would be the same as `not false` which would be `true`.  So here is the equivalent in Java.

Assume `int[] array = {0};`

```
if (array[index] != 0) {
   return -1
}
if (!(array[index] != 0)) // or better `(array[index] == 0)` 
   continue;
}
// at this point array[index] is > 0.
```